# Locator Issue regarding multiple attribute

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

[image]I've located an element correctly by using the following XPath...

```
//a[@class=\"desktop-categoryLink\"][@data-reactid="30"]
```

But when I paste this in my eclipse it looks like below...

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class=\"desktop-categoryLink\"][@data-reactid=\"30\"]")).click();
```

Then I removed the two '\' before and after 30..then it shows an error like "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"..Guys how can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide html code? How do you know that first locator is correct?

Comment: because it matched with one element..i will provide the screenshot above... I am trying to click on the link which is not visible initially...So, I used moveToElement()  and from the fly-out menu, tried to click the link...This is myntra.com

Comment: I asked that question because your xpath looks strange. I would tried something like //a[@class='desktop-categoryLink'][@data-reactid='30']. Moreover maybe better is to use href attribute?

Comment: I tried this  //a[@class='desktop-categoryLink'][@data-reactid='30'].. But now it is throwing  "org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable"  exception

Comment: Ok, that can mean that there is multiple elements that match your search and some are hidden. Please try to use //a[@href='/men-tshirts']

Comment: Tried but still throws the same exception...When opening the browser a pop is displaying above to enable notification for the site..is this having any connection with the test or the cause of failure ?

Comment: Bro, So sorry...For the moveToElement()  method, I didn't use perform() method with that..that's why it didn't locate the 'T-Shirt' link there..Now it's worked fine...It was a mistake of mine...thanks for the quick responses

Answer (score 3):

> Then I removed the two '\' before and after 30..then it shows an error
>   like "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"..Guys
>   how can I resolve this?

You cannot remove the two '\' because that are escape characters for the double quotes. When you remove the backslash you are creating two strings instead of one.
String one will consist of 
`"//a[@class=\"desktop-categoryLink\"][@data-reactid="`
while string two only has the bracket `"]"`. With the 30 being an int in the middle.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367322/what-are-all-the-escape-characters#1367339) to learn more about escape characters in strings